# Distribute items in boxes with equal size

Tags: problem-solving

Suppose that there are $1650$, $1560$ and $1260$ lamps of three types A, B, C respectively. I want to distribute them in boxes with equal sizes so that each box contains the maximum number of lamps of a certain type.

My attempt:

The formula I can think of is:

$$1650+x_1 = 1560+x_2=1260+x_3$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3 =0$$

However, I still need another equation to solve this problem. In general, what is the easy way to solve such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\gcd(1560,1650,1260)=30$$therefore you can put the lamps in boxes with capacity of 30 each containing only one certain type and there are 149 such boxes there